# What type of core do I need to create to find strings like this?

Tags: solr

How would I go about creating a SOLR core to find strings like "consideration of the awardee’s past experience". Currently I get hits on the individual words like "consideration", "past" etc but the document containing the string isn't returned, at least not on the first few pages. Should I use the dismax parser? A different tokenizer than the default?

Comment: Whats the field type used for the field? Can you share the schema used?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your query in `"`. Example:

```
title:"consideration of the awardee’s past experience"
```

If you are interested in similar but not exact matches you can try combining this with a fuzzy search. Example:

```
title:"consideration of the awardee’s past experience"~0.7
```